# Getting value from some?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using some, if condition is true, it will set `Status` in the `Item` but how do I get the value of Qty from matched some in the `json.products`?

```
if (json.products.some(({  Id }) => Id === Item.Id)) {
     Item.Status = {
      "Name": "Processed"
      "Qty": //Get Qty from matched some (from json.products)? 
     } 
}
```

If using `some` is not the right approach, should I use forEach instead?

Comment: `some` in your context is only a existence checking, which returning a boolean, use some other method like `find`/`filter` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find` instead, by passing same *callback* function as `argument`.

```
let product = json.products.find(({  Id }) => Id === Item.Id);
if(product){
   Item.Status = {
     "Name": "Processed"
     "Qty": product.Qty
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```
const matchingProduct = json.products.find(({ Id }) => Id === Item.Id);
if (matchingProduct) {
  Item.Status = {
    Name: "Processed",
    Qty: matchingProduct.Qty,  // or something.
  };
}
```